# queryset filter month returns empty

Tags: python, django

**Edit**: So I dropped this and then waited for a few days it started working! Some how the upgrade to 1.6 took a while to 'propagate'! *shrugs*. Thanks to all who chimed in!

The queryset filter `month` does not seem to be working correctly. I have a bunch of objects in database with model called Note with field `pub_date` storing a `datetime` object. I want to retrieve Note objects by month. So here is a test I did:

```
>>> from blogengine.models import Note
>>> n = Note.objects.all()[0]
>>> n.pub_date
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 8, 21, 15, 14, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> Note.objects.filter(pub_date__year = 2014)
[<Note: Note object>, <Note: Note object>]

>>> Note.objects.filter(pub_date__month =3)
[]
```

As you can see the `year` look up works correctly, giving me the two objects with `year=2014`, but the `month` lookup returns nothing even though there is an object with that month as can be seen from the first example object `n`. This also happens for all other datetime lookups like `day` or `minute`.

Python = 2.7.5
Django 1.6.2

Comment: "When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the database" did you check your configuration?

Comment: @ONi Yes, all my datetimes in database are UTC. But I don't understand why that will affect month and not year?

Comment: It might be that some data is getting lost in translation. Try printing the queryset's query attribute: Note.objects.filter(pub_date__month =3).query

Comment: so that gives me: `<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x3c38110>` But what does that mean?

Comment: I should've said it clearer: print Note.objects.filter(pub_date__month =3).query

Comment: And the print gives me ```SELECT `blogengine_note`.`id`, `blogengine_note`.`slug`, `blogengine_note`.`pub_date`, `blogengine_note`.`_in_reply_to`, `blogengine_note`.`_content` FROM `blogengine_note` WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`blogengine_note`.`pub_date`, 'UTC', America/Los_Angeles)) = 3 ORDER BY `blogengine_note`.`pub_date` DESC```

Comment: Katrik, can you try the following query in mysql (I guess that `python manage.py dbshell` should work for you in this case):  
`SELECT blogengine_note.id, blogengine_note.slug, blogengine_note.pub_date, CONVERT_TZ(blogengine_note.pub_date, 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles') FROM blogengine_note;`  

I hope that it will help you to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @miga the direct db query as you mentioned returns all the Note objects with dates converted to the correct time-zone, which of course does not change the month, so now I am more confused.

Comment: I guess that you should continue with tinkering the db query. Changing one thing at a time and looking for some glue. I think that changing SELECT CONVERT_TZ to SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ...  
will be a good start.

Comment: @miga Actually I did exactly that... and it seems to give the correct month=3! I am inclined to think this is a bug in Django 1.6.2. Also thanks for all your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dropped this and then waited for a few days it started working! Some how the upgrade to 1.6 took a while to 'propagate'! *shrugs*.

Thanks to all who chimed in!

Comment: I am having this exact issue in Django v1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which turned out to be mysql not loading tz info. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454465/8092