# convert timezone returning null

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, convert-tz

I have a query that contains

```
CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@global.time_zone, 'Europe/Madrid')
```

as the value for an insert statement.

This has worked fine on several servers. Now, on a new one, that returns null causing an error.

What can be the cause?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14454465/2091410); hope it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert\_tz returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454304/convert-tz-returns-null)

Comment: @EdGibbs right, that was it.

Comment: @danmullen no, no error message.