# MySQL CONVERT_TZ() returns null when one of the arguments is "+14:00"

Tags: mysql, timezone, convert-tz

I am trying to convert UTC time into the users local time, it works fine until I try to convert the time to +14:00 timezone, the result is always null, anyone has idea?
Here is my code:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(now(), '+00:00', '+14:00')
```

Comment: Is there really a time zone that's 14 hours ahead of GMT?

Comment: @Barmar Yes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00

Comment: Timezones are *weird*.  Is it okay to treat +14 as -10?

Comment: @Barmar:  Such is the way of politics:  it doesn't *have* to make sense.  While there might be bureaucratic reasons for it, the boast "we are ahead of the world" is probably most of the justification.

Comment: @Mr.Llama That will work if you only care about the time of day, but the date will be a day behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL:

[MySQL does not recognize timezone offset UTC +14:00](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63685)

Comment: Thank you! I notice that the submitted date of this bug is in 2011, is there anyway to fix it now?

Comment: Probably not. If they'd actually done anything about it, there would be an update

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that, by using timezone name instead of offset. `UTC +14:00` equals to `Pacific/Kiritimati` timezone. So if You modify query to:

`SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', 'Pacific/Kiritimati')`

or

`SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Pacific/Kiritimati')`

then You'll get valid date, not `NULL`.

**BUT** there is one condition. Your MySQL engine needs timezones list. If above queries still returns `NULL`, it means You don't have timezones list loaded into Your MySQL engine.

Probably You'll have to run also this command:

`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql`

Plese check this thread for more information, about loading timezones list: [convert_tz returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454304/convert-tz-returns-null)

Tested on **MySQL 5.6.36**.