# Why is my Django filter query using dates not returning expected results?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using Django 2.2.6.

I have a model like this:

```
class NetflowRecord(models.Model):
    #############
    # Help Text #
    #############

    min_mac_length_error_message = "Must be at least 12 characters long"
    data_help_text = "Bytes"
    direction_help_text = "True if record reflects downloaded bytes.<br>False if data reflects uploaded bytes."

    ##########
    # Fields #
    ##########

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False, editable=False)
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=False, blank=False, null=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(12, min_mac_length_error_message), validate_mac], editable=False)
    data = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False, help_text=data_help_text, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], editable=False)
    direction = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, help_text=direction_help_text, editable=False)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, related_name="netflow_records")

    ##########
    # Extras #
    ##########

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Netflow Record"
        verbose_name_plural = "Netflow Records"
        ordering = ['mac', 'timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        formatted_date = self.timestamp.astimezone().strftime("%b %d, %Y - %I:%M:%S %p")

        if self.direction:
            return f"Download record for {self.mac} on {formatted_date}"
        else:
            return f"Upload record for {self.mac} on {formatted_date}"
```

Seems pretty basic.
I have a bunch of records in the database in the table this model created.
Using the interactive shell, if I do this:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from my_app.models import NetflowRecord
>>>
>>> for record in NetflowRecord.objects.filter()[:3]:
...     print(record.timestamp)
... 
2020-02-06 19:20:41.758768+00:00
2020-02-06 20:20:46.491537+00:00
2020-02-06 19:07:57.482944+00:00
>>> for record in NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__year=2020)[:3]:
...     print(record.timestamp)
... 
2020-02-06 19:20:41.758768+00:00
2020-02-06 20:20:46.491537+00:00
2020-02-06 19:07:57.482944+00:00
>>> for record in NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__month=2)[:3]:
...     print(record.timestamp)
... 
# Returned None
>>> for record in NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__day=6)[:3]:
...     print(record.timestamp)
... 
# Returned None
>>> today = timezone.now().date()
>>> for record in NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__date=today)[:3]:
...     print(record.timestamp)
...
# Returned None
```

Why is my filter not working when I used `__day`, `__month`, or `__date`?
The Django documentation says they should all work, and if I start a brand new project using the same Django version, I can't replicate the problem - they all work.

Did I screw something up somewhere?

Edit: I was able to replicate it using this minimal code: https://github.com/terminator14/django_filter_problem.git

Just clone it, install dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, edit `db.cnf` to point to your MySQL database, and run `./manage.py migrate; ./manage.py shell`, and do something like:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from test_app.models import NetflowRecord
>>>
>>> for i in range(3):
...     NetflowRecord.objects.create(timestamp=timezone.now())
...
>>> NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__day=timezone.now().day)
```

Edit 2: Installing the latest Django 2 available on PIP (2.2.10) didn't fix the problem. Installing the latest Django 3 available on PIP (3.0.3) DID fix the problem. Is this a bug? Or did Django change the way something works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any query Django runs, you can see exactly what MySQL commands it will run by adding .query.

This let me do this:

```
str(NetflowRecord.objects.filter(timestamp__day=6).query)
```

which showed me a long MySQL command. The important part was this:

```
... WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM CONVERT_TZ(`test_app_netflowrecord`.`timestamp`, 'UTC', 'America/Edmonton')) = 6;
```

Doing some MySQL queries manually, it turned out if I run:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

as shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), it's supposed to give me a date, but it was giving me null. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454465/6423456), this is because MySQL didn't have definitions for timezones loaded.

After running the command from that link (`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql`), now the sample code above with GMT to MET works, and my queries work too.