# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySql is updating the table with incorrect format

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I am having an update query in my java application :

`update STAGE_TBL SET LAST_UPDATE_DTTM = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where ID = 8`

I am getting the `LAST_UPDATE_DTTM` as `2020-07-08-04.15.37 +0530 CST` but I need it in `2020-10-08 08:06:53.812136` (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:ss:Ss`) EST format .

How to do that ?

Comment: Check that `LAST_UPDATE_DTTM` is defined as `TIMESTAMP(6)` in the table structure (not single `TIMESTAMP`). Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` instead of single `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using something like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`?
This should give you the timestamp in the format you want.
You can find more information about the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function in [this blog post](https://database.guide/current_timestamp-examples-mysql/) or in the [MYSQL DOCs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp).

---

To convert the timestamp to EST you could use the following:

```
CONVERT_TZ( UTC_TIMESTAMP, '+0:00', '-4:00');
```

Alternatively:

```
CONVERT_TZ( UTC_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', 'EST');
```

In place of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. For more information about the MYSQL `CONVERT_TZ` Function go [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Here you use MYSQLs UTC timestamp to get a timestamp that is 4 hours before UTC time.

For the second methode to work you need to load a timezone table into mysql:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

You can find more information on how to load timezone tables into MYSQL on different operating systems in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454304/convert-tz-returns-null).